# how to get file mime type with plupload?

Tags: plupload

I'm looking to get the file type when uploading using plupload

e.g.

```
uploader.bind('FilesAdded', function(up, files) {
    $.each(files, function(i, file) {           
        alert(file.type);

    });

    up.refresh(); // Reposition Flash/Silverlight
});
```

if I use file.name and file.id it works

thanks

Comment: I think you need to ask it in plupload forum